# Is this geeksforgeeks trie implementation having a memory leak problem?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, trie

I am reading a [geeksforgeeks_implementation_of_trie](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/), and i find that the `TrieNode` objects that are created by `new` are undeleted, in the main function, there is an undeleted pointer `root`:

```
struct TrieNode *root = getNode();
```

and in function `getNode()` there is also undeleted pointer `pNode`, is there any memory leak? Is there should be a function that is responsible for the destruction of the trie tree composed by pointers?

```
struct TrieNode *getNode(void) 
{ 
    struct TrieNode *pNode =  new TrieNode; 
    pNode->isEndOfWord = false; 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) 
        pNode->children[i] = NULL; 
  
    return pNode; 
}
```

Comment: If this returned a `std::unique_ptr` rather than a raw pointer, there would be no question...

Comment: Code at that "geeks" website is very poor.  Very seldom, if ever is there an actual code example that isn't bug-riddled.  So yes, it leaks memory.

Comment: `struct TrieNode*` should be a sign that the person writing the code does not know `c++` or is being lazy by using the mostly a `c` implementation for `c++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function implies a contract where the caller of the function is responsible for deleting the allocated `TrieNode`. There's only a memory leak if the caller does not honor this contract.

Since you said this `TrieNode` is not deleted anywhere in `main`, there is likely a leak. Unless you can find somewhere this struct is deleted, there's a leak. This is why RAII is such a powerful concept. If there was a `Trie` object that contained all the `TrieNode`s and was responsible for node allocation and deletion, then you wouldn't have to worry about leaks at all.

Making the caller responsible for managing allocated resources is dangerous. Don't do it.

You can argue that this particular implementation isn't necessarily a leak, if the program is simple enough that all it does is acquire the `TrieNode`s, do things with them, and then exit. In that case the memory will be released to the OS on the program exiting anyway. But this is a semantic argument, and providing example code that does this is bad practice, and can lead to cargo cult programmers doing that bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

### To leak or not to leak...

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), a leak *occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages memory allocations in a way that memory which is no longer needed is not released*:

- The role of `getNode()` is to return a pointer to an initialized `TrieNode`.  So it doesn't leak anything by itself: we can assume that according to its purpose, the corresponding object is still needed when the function returns its pointer.
- The calling context indeed leaks memory: as you rightly pointed out, it creates a node with `getNode()` and never deletes that node.  This is bad practice.

But you have to replace this code in its context: the article is a tutorial.  It proposes the deletion as an [additional exercise](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/trie-delete/1).

### Why they do not show deletion in the tutorial

Because deleting `TrieNode` is not an easy thing if you have to take care yourself:  deleting a node requires also to find all the referred nodes that should be deleted as well.  Since a trie is a graph,  more than one node can point to the same destination. So you cannot blindly delete these nodes, if you do not want to risk UB because of dangling pointers and double deletes. You'd need to either implement a marking algorithm or some kind of reference counting

### But don't follow this tutorial

This `TrieNode` implementation is extremely poor: In modern C++:

- you'd let the constructor initialize a `TrieNode`, whether it's a dynamically created node or a local node.
- you'd use a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer.  Since a node can by nature be refererrenced several time,  you'd go for a `shared_ptr`
- you'd probably prefer to use a `vector<shared_ptr<TrieNode>>` or even a `map<char, shared_ptr<TrieNode>>` instead of an old-style array.

But I'd still let you the deletion as an exercise ;-)